# Import modules through CDN in client side js in an express application

Tags: node.js, express, momentjs, ejs

I am using express and ejs templates for a project. And I want to use the library moment.js on the client side javascript file (public/js/app.js) to create a dynamic calendar for which I'm using the CDN link of moment.js but it somehow doesn't work. The import doesnt work.

**Heirarchy**

```
|---index.js
|
|---views
|     |
|     |---calendar.ejs
|
|---public
      |
      |---css
      |    |
      |    |---style.css
      |
      |---js
           |
           |---app.js
```

`index.js`

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('calendar');
});
```

`index.ejs`

```
<head>
    ........
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
</head
<body>
    ........
    <script type="module" src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

It throws error `Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined` each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when you remove `type="module"`:

```
    <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Or you could:

1. copy the code from https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js
2. make a moment.js file in public/js
3. paste the code in there
4. load it in the HTML like so:    `<script src="js/moment.js"></script>`